# how to handle if user cancelled InApp purchase or just another failed state

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, payment

I am trying to handle cancel button by handling SKErrorPaymentCancelled error code. However SKErrorPaymentCancelled error code and SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed state returns same value. So all SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed states act like user canceled the transaction.Is there a way to distinguish these two codes?

my code is like this :

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
{
    if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        [kUIActivator stopAnimating];
        button1.enabled = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wallahi I don't know :( , I have same issue which SKErrorPaymentCancelled and  SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed have same Code in any condition. If someone can answer this issue i will be glad also ....